# How to get special grouped by, nested json back from a sql oracle query?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

The code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
JSON_OBJECT(
ROOM_LIGHT VALUE
JSON_OBJECT
(
'START' VALUE START,
'ENDE' VALUE ENDE,
'RUN' VALUE RUNNING
)
) 
FROM runtime

WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY ROOM_LIGHT;
```

I want this JSON back:

```
{
"ROOM_LIGHT": "01": [
{
"START" :"",
"ENDE"  :"",
"RUNNING": ""
},
{
"START" :"",
"ENDE"  :"", 
"RUNNING": ""
}
],
"ROOM_LIGHT": "02": [
{
"START" :"",
"ENDE"  :"",
"RUNNING": ""
},
{
"START" :"",
"ENDE"  :"", 
"RUNNING": ""
}
]
}
```

My problem is the group by doesn't work. I get this kind of JSON back:

```
{ "ROOM_LIGHT 01": {"START": "", "ENDE":"", "RUNNING":""}},
{ "ROOM_LIGHT 01": {"START": "", "ENDE":"", "RUNNING":""}},
{ "ROOM_LIGHT 01": {"START": "", "ENDE":"", "RUNNING":""}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected output is invalid JSON as you have multiple keys in the same object with the same `ROOM_LIGHT` key.

Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG`:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'ROOM_LIGHT ' || ROOM_LIGHT VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'START' VALUE "START",
             KEY 'ENDE'  VALUE ENDE,
             KEY 'RUN'   VALUE RUNNING
           )
         )
       ) As json
FROM   runtime
GROUP BY ROOM_LIGHT;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE runtime (
  room_light VARCHAR2(20),
  "START"    VARCHAR2(20),
  ende       VARCHAR2(20),
  running    VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO runtime (room_light, "START", ende, running)
SELECT '01', 'abc', 'def', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'mno', 'pqr', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'stu', 'vwx', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: `START` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an identifier unless you use a quoted identifier.*

Outputs:

| JSON |
| --- |
| {"ROOM_LIGHT 01":[{"START":"abc","ENDE":"def","RUN":"Y"},{"START":"mno","ENDE":"pqr","RUN":"N"},{"START":"ghi","ENDE":"jkl","RUN":"Y"}]} |
| {"ROOM_LIGHT 02":[{"START":"stu","ENDE":"vwx","RUN":"Y"}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V2z0cStR)

#### Update

If you are having problems with the size of the string then use `RETURNING CLOB` to return a `CLOB`, instead of a `VARCHAR2`:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'ROOM_LIGHT ' || ROOM_LIGHT VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'START' VALUE "START",
             KEY 'ENDE'  VALUE ENDE,
             KEY 'RUN'   VALUE RUNNING
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) As json
FROM   runtime
GROUP BY ROOM_LIGHT;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_126rnPz)

Comment: Thank you for your solution!
I know START is reserved but I changed the words from the original data :).
I have the problem now, that the output value is too large for the SQL Developer. You have any idea for that too ?

Comment: @JazCodes Use `RETURNING CLOB`.

Comment: Thank you ! You also know how to get the ROOM_LIGHT also in one list / row? So that the result is one line, because at the moment we have for each room light an extra line but I need them all in one row.

Comment: @JazCodes Are you after `JSON_OBJECTAGG` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S5ij2iE9)?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to group elements into one array :

```
SELECT ROOM_LIGHT, 
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'ROOM_LIGHT : ' || ROOM_LIGHT value
          JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT (
             'START' VALUE STARTE,
             'ENDE' VALUE ENDE,
             'RUNE' VALUE RUNNING
           )
          )
         ) as json
FROM runtime
GROUP BY ROOM_LIGHT;
```

Result :

```
ROOM_LIGHT  JSON
01          {"ROOM_LIGHT : 01":[{"START":10,"ENDE":4,"RUNE":5},{"START":10,"ENDE":14,"RUNE":5}]}
02          {"ROOM_LIGHT : 02":[{"START":10,"ENDE":4,"RUNE":5}]}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBbIf7Bj)